# AWS CDK: Vpc subnet conflicts with another subnet

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, vpc

I want to create an OpenSearch domain in AWS CDK within a VPC. I've made some progress, but I'm stuck with an issue regarding CIDR.

```
var vpc = new Vpc(scope, "Vpc");
var subnet = new Subnet(scope, "Subnet", new SubnetProps
{
     VpcId = vpc.VpcId,
     CidrBlock = "10.0.1.0/24",
     AvailabilityZone = "us-east-1a"
});
var domain = new Domain(scope, "Domain", new DomainProps
{
     Vpc = vpc,
     VpcSubnets = new SubnetSelection[] 
     { 
         new SubnetSelection
         {
             Subnets = new Subnet[]
             {
                 subnet
             }
         }
     },
     SecurityGroups = new SecurityGroup[]
     {
         new SecurityGroup(scope, "SecurityGroup", new SecurityGroupProps
         {
             Vpc = vpc
         })
     },
     // other property initializations are omitted
}
```

The error I'm getting is `The CIDR '10.0.1.0/24' conflicts with another subnet`. How can this be true if I'm creating a brand new `Vpc` with only one subnet? I assume there may be more subnets that are created implicitly. How can I address this issue?

Currently I don't care for multiple AZs so I need to place the domain within a single subnet.

Comment: The subnet can be any internal subnet in your intranet, not just in the AWS domain.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I thought the subnet would be scoped to the VPC which is a new resource in this example.

Comment: Unless you VPC is private, it is a subnet on your intranet and is connected to every other machine in your domain on your ethernet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VPC construct's [IpAddresses](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.Vpc.html#ipaddresses) and [SubnetConfiguration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.Vpc.html#subnetconfiguration) props allow you to customise the CIDR range and subnets.

Your VPC constructor is not defining these props, so the defaults (`10.0.0.0/16` allocated to 2 subnets) are applied instead.  These defaults are conflicting with your manually created subnet.

Pardon my bad C#, but you'll want a VPC constructor something like this:

```cs
Vpc vpc = new Vpc(this, "VPC", new VpcProps {
    IpAddresses = IpAddresses.Cidr("10.0.0.0/24")
    MaxAzs = 1,
    SubnetConfiguration = new ISubnetConfiguration[]
    {
        new SubnetConfiguration
        {
            SubnetType = SubnetType.PUBLIC,
            Name = "Public"
        }
    }
});
```

See the [Ip Address Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2-readme.html#ip-address-management) section in the docs for details.